# How can I place a button on each row in titanium studio?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, httpclient

I want to be able to put a different button inside every row (createTableViewRow). I have created five buttons (Titanium.UI.createButton), but I don't know how to place all five of my buttons for each created row.
Can somebody give me a hint on how to do it?

```
function sendAjax() {

    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    xhr.onerror = function(e){
        var error = e.error;
        alert(error);               
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    xhr.send();

    var tv = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
        height: Titanium.UI.SIZE,
        width: Titanium.UI.FILL
    });
    win2.add(tv);

    xhr.onload = function() {

        var data = [];
        var schools = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        for (s in schools) {
            data.push(Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            title: schools[s].Name
        }));
    }
    tv.data = data;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
backgroundColor : '#fff'
});

var tableData = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Button ' + i,
    width : 100,
    height : 40,
    buttonid : i    //our custom button property
});
row.add(button);
tableData.push(row);

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('button ' + e.source.buttonid + ' clicked.');
    alert('Button ' + e.source.buttonid);
});
}

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
data : tableData
});

win.add(tableView);

win.open();
```

This answer find from [here](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/128210/button-in-a-table-view-row)

**UPDATE :**

```
function sendAjax() {

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onerror = function(e){
    var error = e.error;
    alert(error);               
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
xhr.send();

var tv = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    height: Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    width: Titanium.UI.FILL
});
win2.add(tv);

xhr.onload = function() {

    var data = [];
    var schools = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (s in schools) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
    var rowItem = Ti.UI.createView({
       height : 40,
       width : Ti.UI.FILL,
       layout : 'horizontal'
    });
    row.add(rowItem);
    var title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
       height : 40,
       text : schools[s].Name,
       width : Ti.UI.SIZE
    });

    rowItem.add(title);
    var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title : 'click ',
        width : 100,
        height : 40,
        buttonid : s    //our custom button property
    });
    rowItem.add(button);
    data.push(row);

    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('button ' + JSON.stringify(e.source.buttonid) + ' clicked.');

    });
    };

    tv.data = data;
};
};
```

Don't forget to mark this as correct answer If this useful.

Comment: Hi, nice code, but where in your code are you using json GET? and can I sign different adventListener to the buttons?

Comment: can you tell which line it shows the error. please ensure you have declare var data = [] outside the for loop.

Comment: Did you got the answer? for me its works fine for me.

Comment: Nice code, but when I click the button nothing happens... The log is showing: [INFO] button objects clicked. I want to populate my rows from a json file...

Comment: Change inside the button click listener 

Ti.API.info('button ' + JSON.stringify(e.source.buttonid) + ' clicked.');

Actually your getting row obj as json. for printing json you need to use JSON.stringify(jsonObj)

Comment: Hi, Ok Its working know... But I wonder how I can sign differents addEventListener to each button?

Comment: If its working mark this as answer. You can call different functions inside the click listener eg: if(e.source.buttonid.name == "xxxx"){ xxxxCalled(); }

Comment: Hi, I just wonder why the created button, cant have right: 10. It wont place the button on the right...

Answer (score 1):

You should add the listener event on the tableView, not on each buttons inside the row :

```
tableView.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.source.buttonid) {
       //it's a button
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, nice code, It solved my problem with having differents listeners to each button.